# Chrome under playwright: Conflict in high dynamic range setting

Tags: google-chrome, graphics, playwright, headless-browser

We tried launching the same version of chrome manually and then using playwright in Java. We see a conflict in HDR setting.

A same version of chrome was launched manually and then using playwright. We observed that the following query yields different results.

```
console.log("HDR:", window.matchMedia("(dynamic-range: high)").matches)
```

On manually launched chrome, the output is true, whereas under playwright, the output is false. What causes this conflict? How do I resolve this?

Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conflict is caused by the way that Playwright emulates the user's environment.

When you launch Chrome manually, it will detect whether the user's device supports HDR and set the `dynamic-range` media query accordingly.

However, when you launch Chrome using Playwright, it will not detect whether the user's device supports HDR, so it will always return false for the `dynamic-range: high` media query.